# Determine if the function $f(x,y)=2^{x-1}\cdot(2y-1)$, where $x,y \in \mathbb N_{+}$, is injective

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

> We have a function of two variables $f(x,y)=2^{x-1}\cdot(2y-1)$ where $x,y \in N_{+}$. Find out if function is injective and determine its value range.

I don't know now how to examine if function is injective but I think the value range is $N_+ \times N_+$

Comment: are there 2 different pairs $(x,y)$ and $(x'y')$ such that $2^{x-1}\cdot(2y-1)=2^{x'-1}\cdot(2y'-1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y,x',y'\in\Bbb N$ such that
$$f(x,y)=f(x',y')$$
Assume WLOG that  $x>x'$ then
$$\underbrace{2^{x-x'}(2y-1)}_{\text{even}}=\underbrace{(2y'-1)}_{\text{odd}}$$
which's a contradiction so $x=x'$ and then $y=y'$. Conclude.

Comment: Excellent argument, Sami!